# how to ensure the browser can support **{get X() {}}**

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

i refuse to use `__defineProperty__` and instead prefer the alternative syntax **{get X() {}}**

However this will not work on IE.

Aside from browser detection, what is the best way i can detect that a browser supports the newer syntax?

Edit: ok actually im not trying to detect IE in particular but redirect those "browsers that do not support **get X(){}** syntax" to **notsupported.html**. I believe that there's some way to do it and am working on it but in case someone already has this problem before and had a solution..

Edit 2: btw doesn't that mean that no one (erm other than me) uses the **get X(){}** syntax since its not supported by all (or not supported by the 5 major browsers yet) ?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use defineProperty?

Comment: my reason is that IE will support it anyway in the near future, and when that happens i don't want to rewrite anything.. and of course.. if possible no one wants to write _____defineGetter_____ when there's a better way to write it..

Comment: IE8 has no way to emulate a getter. The best you can do is methods. There is also nothing wrong with `defineProperty` as it allows you to inject properties with getter functions into existing objects.

Comment: i mean i know IE has no way around this that's why i want to kick it out. but to be able to kick it out i need a way to determine if the browser can support [gs]etters

Comment: use IE conditional statements to not load any javascript. Basically for IE<9 users to turn javascript off. Of course since you apply to good standards your website works without javascript and all your javascript is unobtrusively and asychronously loaded from one location so this is a trivial change to make.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, you cannot force older (current!) browsers to accept newer syntax.  And what would you do with browser detection?  Use the old syntax for the old browsers and new syntax otherwise?  Then you're writing the same code twice.

Decide on a set of browsers you need to support, determine what features they can all guarantee to you, then limit yourself to those features.  That's how web development works.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an ES5 feature that is not commonly implemented.

You *want* to use *syntax* that common javascript interpreters cannot recognise.

There is no way to emulate it.

I recommend you just use

```
{
    getX: function() { ... }
}
```

If you check the [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/es5-getters-setters-versus-getter-setter-methods/4). Then you'll see using ES5 is 15 times slower. Just stick with ES3.

There is little you can do about this as there is no way to emulate getters in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function browserSupportsGetterAndSetterSyntax() {
  try {
    return eval('({ get x() { return 3; }}).x') == 3;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```